# structure bullets lists in org doc

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am working on editing the following text

```py
3. Series
a. creating a series
- dict
- ndarray
- scalar
- lists

b. slicing
```

The desired edited result is

```py
3. Series
  a. creating a series
    - dict
    - ndarray
    - scalar
    - lists
  b. slicing
```

Get it down with a cumbersome steps line by line

1) cursor on  head of line `a.creating a sereis`, invoking C-2 space
2) cursor  to head of next line, invoking C-u space
3) repeat step 2 to line `-list`
4) repeat step 1 to line `b.slicing`

Detoured by that, because the straightforward operations do not work

1) place cursor on front of line and invoke Tab, they stay still.
2)  do batch operations to select them all then invoking C-2 space, also take no effects.

Is it possible to get the job done with an easy solution?

Comment: This should probably be moved to Emacs SE. The SO site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable letters to be used as plain text lists in org-mode:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32743

Use `M-RET` when inserting elements and `M-` arrow keys for adjusting structure of the current item or region.  (`S-M-` arrow keys to include nested items).  Additionally, `C-x TAB` followed by arrows for manually adjusting indent of regions.